# System of equations over the field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, systems-of-equations

I'm new to this topic and trying to solve system of equations over the field $Z_{3}$:
$$\begin{array}{rcr} x+2z & = & 1 \\ y+2z & = & 2 \\ 2x+z & = & 1 \end{array}$$

I solved the system but I have roots:
$$x=1/3,
y=4/3, z=1/3$$ and it's probably not right. Can you help with this one?

Comment: Adding the first and last equations over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ gives $0=2\,$, so the system has no solutions.

Comment: Indeed, it can't be right, because in $\mathbb Z_3$, $3\equiv 0$, and therefore you're dividing by zero for all variables.

Answer (score 0):

Adding all equations gives $y+2z=1$ and with $y+2z=2$ we get a contradiction.

Thus, the system  has no solutions in $\mathbb Z_3$.

Answer (score 0):

So start with the 3 equations

X + 2z = 1

Y + 2z = 2

2x + z = 1

The first and last equations equal each other so we know X = Z

Now with the second question we can use to solve for Y

Y + 2z = 2

We need to turn that into

1/2Y + Z = 1

Now combine it with equation 3

1/2Y + Z = X + 2z

Simplify

1/2Y = X + Z

Y = 2x + 2z

Now solve for Z or X by reworking equations 1 and 3 into

-2z + 1 = -1/2Z + 1/2

Solve for Z

1 = 1 1/2Z + 1/2

1/2 = 1 1/2Z

Divide by 1 1/2

Z = 1/3

Z = X

X = 1/3

Now solve for Y using X and Z

Y = 2x + 2z

Y = 2(1/3) + 2(1/3)

Y = 2/3 + 2/3

Y = 1 1/3

So in the end the answers are

X = 1/3

Y = 1 1/3

Z = 1/3